# Can't change permission in /media folder ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu-10.04

I have mounted various partions in ubuntu by creating folders in /media.

Now when i log via root and execute `chmod 700 /media/folder` then permission stays same 777.

They don't change even with root

I am using this in /etc/fstab

```
/dev/sdb1 /media/Server ntfs defaults 0 0
```

How can i make that Server is only read/write by one user called user1

and in other folder /Server/abc i want to give all rw permission

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unmount partition, change permission to 777 and then re-mount.
Either way, the permission is carried over from where ever you're mounting the partition from so you need to change that at source server.